# How to continuously reading in frames while at the same time do image processing for every 100 frames

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to do image processing with OpenCV and Python. The input video will be live stream from a network camera.
My plan is to contiously read the frames. At the same time, for every 100 frames, process the video and get some results (the trajectory for example). The video processing takes around 1/25 second for each frame, so it is similar to the frame rate of the video.

For now I'm testing with a recorded video. My idea is to use multiprocess in this case. One process keeps reading the frames from the video and store the frames in the queue. The other process reads frame batches from the queue and do some image processing.
But in this case, a lot of frames get lost / are not dealt with. For example, there are 600 frames in the video, but only 300 frames were processed. I guess it was because that reading the frames is much faster than the processing?
In this case, what methods can help to avoid the situation where the image processing miss a lot of frames?
Thanks!

```
def image_put(vidpath, q, end_event):
    # cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidpath)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Read failed")
        return

    while True:
        if q.qsize() > 100:
            q.get()


        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        q.put(frame)

    cap.release()
    # q.put(None)
    end_event.set() 

def image_get(q, end_event, result_q):
    cnt = 0
    frame_batch = []

    while not end_event.is_set() or not q.empty():
        frame = q.get()
        if frame is None:  # Termination signal
            break
        frame_batch.append(frame)

        if len(frame_batch) == 100:
            cnt += 100
            candidates_points = process_frames(frame_batch)
            result_q.put(candidates_points)
            frame_batch = []
    print(f"{cnt} frames were processed")

def run_single_cam(vidpath):

    # Queue and multiprocess setting
    queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=1000)
    result_queue = mp.Queue()
    end_event = mp.Event()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=image_put, args=(vidpath, queue, end_event)),
                 mp.Process(target=image_get, args=(queue, end_event, result_queue))]

    [process.start() for process in processes]
    [process.join() for process in processes]

    # Process the frame batch
    while not result_queue.empty():
        # ... post processing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = time.time()
    mp.set_start_method("spawn")
    vidpth = "xxx.mp4"
    run_single_cam(vidpth)
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"Time used is {t2-t1}")
```

Comment: how do both processes communicate with each other? How do you share the queue between the processes? Maybe the producer is killing the queue after all images were captured, before the consumer could process all of them?

Comment: @Micka, when all images are captured, the producer does not kill the queue I think. It set an end event to notify the consumer. I have added the code block. Could you please kindly have a look? Thanks.

Comment: Your function that puts frames into the queue is also extracting frames from the queue so they are competing which seems wrong. Also the queue length is not a good measure of the frame number. Also, why are you putting frames you don't want in the queue anyway?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Indeed... I don't know why I wrote it like that. It seems that after replacing q.get() with sleep, it is able to get all the frames from a recording. And for live stream, it works without sleeping, though there is huge latency.